# Friend share database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

First of all, I'm not trying to create a social network, facebook is big enough! (comic) I've chosen this question as example because it fits exactly on what I'm trying to do.

I have in MySQL a users table and a user_connections table with whom i can share my photos. But it is just one way.

```
   Users Table:

   userid  username
   1       John
   2       Amalia
   3       Stewie
   4       Stuart
   5       Ron

   User Connections Table:
   user_id connections_ids
   1       2,3
   2       3,5
```

connection_ids column is in blob datatype so it can store lot of user ids.
 I am thinking of another database design to store all the data and also efficiently querying that data.
 Right now i have to get first all the connection ids from query and then split into array. Again writing query to select photos they created.

Comment: storing a comma separated list is always asking for trouble for efficient querying. It is better to store sets of data with a row per relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a table with

```
user_id , connected_user_id
```

where you can map the connections between users.

This way you end up with a seperate line for each connection between two users.

From the database design view this is much more efficient as you can use indexes on both column speeding up the queries.

For example you could get all the connections for a specific user by such query:

```
SELECT 
  um.connected_user_ids 
FROM 
  user_mapping AS um
JOIN
  users AS u ON (um.user_id = u.user_id)
WHERE 
  u.user_id = <SEARCHED ID>
```

which just gives a complete list without having to cut or split the result.
And further data can simply be joined as well.